# Binary content in XML - Pros and cons?

Tags: xml, web-services, data-transfer

What are your thoughts on binary content in XML vs. mere references to the location of the data?

I am working on a project, where the system needs to exchange complex data -- often consisting of  a lot of different files (usually cad-files). A lot of the material to be sent is confidential. My colleagues have been thinking about embedding files as binary content in XML rather than referencing it, but I am not sure of the consequences. I hope You can help me.

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: Posting this as a comment rather than an answer since I'm biased against XML.  XML is 80% of the time not the right solution to begin with.  Also, if you do include binary, I would not include raw binary but rather base 64 or even hex.  I'm not sure how most XML parsers would feel about binary blobs.

Comment: Corbin you can't include raw binary in XML, so it has to be base64 encoded.

Comment: I want to emphasize Richard's comment: **XML cannot contain arbitrary binary content**. The XML 1.0 spec is very restrictive in the bytes that it allows in a file. The XML 1.1 spec allows everything except NUL, but arbitrary binary data will have embedded NULs.

Comment: @Corbin - check out "Description" section of the Nokogiri site (http://nokogiri.org/) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the binary data is large then you will almost certainly incur a performance penalty by embedding it in base64 rather than referencing it. But it may be a price worth paying for the convenience (and perhaps security). It's very hard to advise on design decisions like this without having a full immersion in the project requirements and culture.

Comment: The cost of XML parsing is dominated by the "read next character" loop. If you store the data embedded in XML, then all operations on the data will incur this per-character cost. If it's an external referenced file, then many operations will be possible without this cost.